# Construction of irreps of path algebra of cyclic quiver, classification of all finite-dimensional irreps.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Crossposted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250268/construction-of-irreps-of-path-algebra-of-cyclic-quiver-classification-of-all-f).

Let $Q$ be a quiver with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ such that $Q$ has a single edge $i \to i + 1$, for every $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$, one edge $n \to 1$, and no other edges. In other words, $Q$ is a cyclic quiver with $n > 1$ vertices. I am looking for a precise reference for the following.

1. The construction of an irrep of $\mathbb{C}Q$ of (total) dimension $> 1$.
2. The classification of all finite dimensional irreps of $\mathbb{C}Q$ up to isomorphism.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note: It is called the path algebra, not the group algebra.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks, I've fixed that.

Comment: Do you know what a representation of a quiver is? If so, look for irreps with vector spaces at each vertex of dimension at most $1$: you should have no trouble finding them. That'll give you irreps of dimension $>1$. I doubt there is a reference for this, as it is an extremely elementary exercise. (You can learn about representations of quiver in the book by Skowronski, Assem and Simson, among many other places)

Comment: As for your second point: that algebra is infinite dimensional and of infinite representation type, so there are many fin.dim irreps! Making the list is not something one can do out of thin air. You should tell us what your background is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a lovely answer which [Johannes Hahn](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3041/johannes-hahn) gave on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/250271/98682).

> Every irreducible finite-dimensional representation is either $1$-dimensional (and there are exactly $n$ of them, corresponding to the vertices) or $n$-dimensional and they can be indexed by non-zero, complex numbers.
>
> Proof: Let $V$ be an irreducible representation, $V=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}/n} V_i$ its standard decomposition given by the vertices and $f_i : V_i\to V_{i+1}$ the linear maps given by the edges. Let $L:=f_{n-1}\ldots f_1 f_0$ be the endomorphism of $V_0$ given by the closed loop in the quiver.
>   If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then there is a eigenvector $v_0$ of $L$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ (we can assume that there are eigenvectors at all by assuming $V_0\neq 0$ wlog). Define $v_1:=f_0(v_0), v_2:=f_1(v_1), \ldots, v_{n-1}:=f_{n-2}(v_{n-2})$.
>
> If $\lambda=0$, then $f_i(v_i)=0$ for some $i$ and $\mathbb{C} v_i$ is a one-dimensional submodule. By simplicity it is the whole of $V$ and we're in the first case.
>
> If $\lambda\neq 0$, then all $v_i$ are nonzero and $\sum_i \mathbb{C}v_i$ is a submodule. By simplicity it is all of $V$, $\{v_i\}$ is a basis and one can easily write down all matrices of the edge elements w.r.t. this basis. Therefore this is a complete set of pairwise non-isomorphic irreducibles.
>
> ---
>
> In fact it should be possible to describe all finite-dimensional modules in terms of a Jordan normal form of $L$. More abstractly there should be something close to a Morita equivalence between the quiver algebra $\mathbb{C}Q$ and $e_0 \mathbb{C}Q e_0$ which is just the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[L]$. Note that the irreducible finite-dimensional representations of $\mathbb{C}[L]$ are parametrized by complex numbers. There seems to be some sort of geometry here lurking in the background where $Irr(\mathbb{C}[L])$ is just the affine line and $Irr(\mathbb{C}Q)$ is the affine line with $n$-fold origin. Maybe some algebraic geometer can shed some light on this observation.